# Flutter Dropdown: Error: Object? newValue issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am a few weeks into a flutter. I like it a lot but I have an issue that I don't understand.
I used the approach below for a drop drown. It works just fine in the dartpad but Visio throws an error and I am not sure what to do about it. Please help.

Error:

> Object? newValue
>  A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a
> variable of type 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or
> casting the right-hand type to 'String'.dartinvalid_assignment

Code:

```
DropdownButton(
   hint: Text('Pick a category'),
   value: _selectedCategory,
   onChanged: (newValue) {
      setState(() {
         _selectedCategory = newValue;
      });
   },
   items: _categories.map((category) {
      return DropdownMenuItem(
             child: new Text(category),
             value: category,
      );
    }).toList(),
 ),
```

Comment: pls, show _selectedCategory and _categories declarations

Comment: Only do  _selectedCategory = newValue as String;

Comment: thank you. I tried it. I get another error in this case, saying that _selectedCategory hasn't been initialized.

Comment: that's why I asked to show the variable declaration

Comment: Thank you, Claudio, you were right, I needed to add '?.'
So it looks like String? _selectedCategory;

Answer (score 0):

```
DropdownButton(
              hint: Text("State"),
              value: "Gujarat",
              items: [
                ...statelist
                    .map((e) =>
                        DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: e, child: Text(e)))
                    .toList(),
              ],
              
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                  child: DropdownButton(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp,color: appStyle.Colors('white'),),
                                      iconSize: 30,
                                      items: ProductCategories.map((dynamic map){
                                        return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                          value: map['Id'].toString(),
                                          child: new Text(map['Name'],
                                              style: new TextStyle(color:  appStyle.Colors('primaryTextTheme'))),
                                        );
                                      }).toList(),
                                      onChanged: (value) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          selectCategoryName(ProductCategories,value);
                                        }
                                        );
                                      }
                                  )),
```

this is the code for dropdown in my project , Feel free to question about it if you use it

Comment: List<dynamic> ProductCategories=[];

_analyzeCategories(value){
    print(appStyle.showDebug('WarnLog', value));
    for(var counter=0;counter < value.length;counter++){
      try {
        ProductCategories.add({'Id':value[counter]['_id'],'Name':value[counter]['Name']});
      } catch (e) {
        print('eerrr--> $e');
      }
    }
  }

      _analyzeCategories("YourData"),

Comment: I have used it like this  you can change it to your keys